# What does the phrase "behind deadline" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

If someone (or something) is behind deadline, does it mean that she/he has already missed a deadline or does it mean that she/he is about to miss a deadline ?

Comment: What is the context for this? I don't believe have heard "behind deadline," though I have heard "behind on my work" or "missing deadlines" or "past the deadline." Lacking an article, I would say a non-native is speaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means they've already missed the deadline.  If they haven't missed the deadline, but their current progress indicates that they will, then they are *[behind schedule](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/behind+schedule)*.

Comment: +1 After all, that's why it's called a dead**line**, isn't it? Once you cross that, it's pretty much over. Great analogy with _behind schedule_.